# Как получить элемент массива?

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте)

Есть массив $main с такой структурой:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 50
        [pagetitle] => Документ 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 48
        [pagetitle] => Документ 2
    )
    и т.д.
)
```

при попытке:

```
$submain = $main[1]
```

возвращает пустое значение, а хотелось бы получить тот массив...

Почему это происходит? И как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Во первых - здесь нет объектов, во вторых - $main[1] должно работать

Comment: Однако нет(

Comment: Ну я даже пробовать не буду, так попросту не бывает. Значит вам пора спать и вы стршно тупите в чем то эллементарном. У меня такое не раз было =)

Comment: )))Вот так вот работает) но эт тупняк ваще...
    $doc = 5;
    $i=0;
    foreach($main as $child)
    {
       if($doc != $i){
       $i++;
    }
     else{
       $submainId = $child->id; 
       break;
    }    
   }

или же надо было изначально $submainId = $main[1]->id???

Comment: [Вот ваш код в действии](http://codepad.org/plVbiyAY). Как видим, всё работает нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если

```
$main = Array
(
    0 => Array    (
        'id' => 50,
        'pagetitle' => 'Документ 1'
    ),
    1 => Array    (
        'id' => 48,
        'pagetitle' => 'Документ 2'
    ),
);
```

то

```
$submain = $main[1];
определит  $submain как массив 
Array    (
        [id] => 48,
        [pagetitle] => 'Документ 2'
    )
```

но никак не пустым значением. 
напишите полный пример кода.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то в вашем случае массив $main - двумерный, поэтому `$main[1]` возвращает подмассив

```
 [1] => Array
     (
         [id] => 48
         [pagetitle] => Документ 2
     )
```

А, как известно, стандартными принтами и эхоми массив в браузер не вывести, поэтому тут надо применять print_r();Чтобы вывести, например, значение [id], надо так:

```
$submain = $main[1][0];
```